# Kleene Closure in Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, kleene-star, chomsky-normal-form

Let *n* be any terminal.

Consider the following, presumably correct, representation of the kleene star over *n*:

```
N → n N | ε
```

(where ε is the empty terminal.)

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form):

> *Every grammar in Chomsky normal form is context-free, and conversely, every context-free grammar can be transformed into an equivalent one which is in Chomsky normal form.*

I cannot see how the above grammar could be transformed to CNF.

- Is the grammar not context-free?
- Is there in fact a way to represent it in CNF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, this can be written in CNF. Here is one such grammar:

> S → ε | n | NA
>
> N → n
>
> A → n | NA

Therefore, the language is context-free.

Hope this helps!